# http.post doesn't compile when options is passed as a variable instead of a literal

Tags: angular5

I notice that the following code doesn't compile (options is passed as a variable `httpOptions`)

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: true, 
  observe: 'response'
};

return this.http.post(this.SIGNIN_USER_URL, body, httpOptions); // options is passed as a variable `httpOptions`
```

I get the following error

```
Argument of type '{ 
    headers: HttpHeaders; 
    observe: string; 
    responseType: string;
}' is not assignable to parameter of type'{ 
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: "body";
    params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean;
    respons...'.

Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.'
```

But the following code does (the options are passed as a literal object)

```js
return this.http.post(this.SIGNIN_USER_URL, body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    withCredentials: true, 
    observe: 'response'
})
```

Why?

Comment: Seems like the TypeScript compiler just isn't smart enough to know your `observe` property isn't any `string` but a specific one. Maybe giving a type assertion on it would help (e.g. `as 'response'` or `as HttpObserve`)

Comment: `observe: 'response' as 'response'` worked. Happy to accept your comment if you could convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, without help, the TypeScript compiler will assume the string given could be any string and thus inferred its type as `string`.

The [`HttpClient.post(...)` method's `options` parameter](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d2e7c99a93393ae5695dd3d374288afad2962b37/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L1768-L1782) however is more restrictive and only accepts an `HttpObserve` type ([which only allows `'body' | 'events' | 'response'`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d2e7c99a93393ae5695dd3d374288afad2962b37/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L51)) for the `observe` property.

If you use a type assertion to help the compiler out you will fix your issue:

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
  withCredentials: true, 
  observe: 'response' as 'response'
};
```